# jBox2D Android become very slow on mobil phone after 80-90 dynamic bodies

Tags: android, box2d

I have a simple game with 20-30 bodies (static, and dynamic)

If I add some more Dynamic bodies and joints (over 80-90 item), then the Box2D will be very laggy, and a little slow..

Am I doing something wrong, or this is the limit of JBox2D? If I change to Box2D JNI via java native calls, is will be faster?

Comment: don't know about jBox2D, but i know that the original version of FantasticContraption which  i'm pretty sure used Box2D got laggy on powerful computers at around 130 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I heard the fastest implementation of Box2D for Android is there: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/ 
AndEngine is using that implementation instead of jBox2D and they're happy they switched to that version :)